# C binary operator applyed on width of LVALUE or RVALUE

Tags: c, casting, binary, rvalue

How does C handle binary operators? Does the standard require compilers to cast it to the LVALUE or needn't it?

The concrete problem I discovered looks as follows:

```
typedef union {
  unsigned long _Data;
  struct {
    unsigned long  _Reserved    : 28;  
    unsigned long  _Info        : 1;
    unsigned long  _Reserved2   : 3;
  };
} S_INFO;

S_INFO Variable;
```

With these defines, the instruction

```
Variable._Data &= ~3uL;
```

compiles different than the instruction

```
Variable._Data &= ~3u;
```

In the 16 bit architecture at hand, int is 2 bytes wide and long is 4 bytes wide.

The compiler seems to apply the & operator to the width of the literal (RVALUE), not to the width of the LVALUE Variable._Data.

Did I discover a a compiler bug or is this correct behaviour according to the C standard?

Comment: Additional info: The second instruction clears the top 16 bit of Variable._Data.

Comment: Names starting with underscore plus uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation never use them! (You can use lowercase, though, which is also more common in C for members).

Comment: Get pen & paper and write down the bit-patterns for both constants. Then manually process the expression on those patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "reserved for the implementation"?

Comment: They are reserved for the implementation. What is unclear about that? See the standard, 7.1.3

Comment: Would you please post your findings as to exactly how the two fragments are compiled differently?

Comment: @Olaf I actually think they're reserved "for any use", that's what the C11 draft says. This is splitting hairs, I know. :)

Comment: Ah. Probably I now got it. The compiler probably does a cast, but only *after* the binary not.

Comment: @unwind: As we are nit-picking;-): "Any use" in the sense of the standard library and the implementation and not only at file-level (like the `_` + lowercase), but anywhere. But without further context, "any use" reads as if they could be legal for user code, too, which they are actually not. I think that was an acceptable shortening for a comment.

Comment: @Coda Casts are always explicitly by the user (with the cast operator). The compiler will never implicitly **cast**. But there are of course the integer promotions.

Comment: Thanks.

So the 7.1.3 section of the C standard has to be interpreted as a prohibition to use undersore + uppercase for any user program identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for you to post your findings as to precisely how the two fragments of code are compiled differently, (and since my comment appears to have prompted you to think of an answer, but I am not sure that this is the right answer,) let me just say that what is probably happening is this:

The instruction `Variable._Data &= ~3uL;` causes an unsigned long literal to be ANDed with a long value.

The instruction `Variable._Data &= ~3u;` takes an unsigned (*not* long) literal, zero-extends it to long, and then ANDs it with a long value.

So, these instructions compile differently most probably due to the way you declare the literal in the right operand.  This probably has nothing to do with the left operand, nor with the operation that you are performing between the operands.

Anyhow, at this point, this is my guess; please post your findings as to precisely how the two fragments of code are compiled differently, and I may amend my answer.

Comment: Additional info: The second instruction clears the top 16 bit of Variable._Data.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Comment: Too short time to edit the old comment.... Sorry, I'm new to this platform.

Thank you for your answer. This basically is what I assumed with "The compiler probably does a cast, but only after the binary not.".

Regarding your answer, I looked at the disassembly. The result is what I described in "Additional info: The second instruction clears the top 16 bit of Variable._Data.". This basically is what you assumed now, too.

Btw, I also reproduced the problem at [link](https://ideone.com/XKu5rI). With the different operations torn apart, it become more comprehensive.

Comment: @Coda Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, these two expressions are not equal:

```
Variable._Data &= ~3uL;
```

```
Variable._Data &= ~3u;
```

Both will zero-out the least significant two bits. But only the second will zero-out the most significant 16 bits. Remember on your machine, the type int has a width of 16 bits, and long a width of 32 bits.

The unary `~` operator will be applied to the integer literals before the `&=` operation is performed. The differences (on your machine) are:

Operation ~3LU results in: 0xFFFFFFFC

Operation ~3U results in: 0xFFFC and is then promoted to long: 0x0000FFFC

The results of applying those two values on `Variable._Data` are different as described above.

First one is:

```
Variable._Data &= 0xFFFFFFFC;
```

and the second one is:

```
Variable._Data &= 0x0000FFFC;
```